# Highlighting particular references in .bib file

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, highlighting

I have the following sample .tex file

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{soul}

\begin{document}
    
This is the file \cite{kang2020energy,pilakkat2019improved,ram2020performance}

\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{abc}  
    
    \end{document}
```

The .bib file goes like this

```
@article{kang2020energy,
    title={{Energy systems for climate change mitigation: A systematic review}},
    author={{Kang, Jia-Ning and Wei, Yi-Ming and Liu, Lan-Cui and Han, Rong and Yu, Bi-Ying and Wang, Jin-Wei}},
    journal={{Applied Energy}},
    volume={{263}},
    pages={{114602}},
    year={{2020}},
    publisher={{Elsevier}}
}
@article{pilakkat2019improved,
    title={An improved {P}\&{O} algorithm integrated with artificial bee colony for photovoltaic systems under partial shading conditions},
    author={Pilakkat, Deepthi and Kanthalakshmi, S},
    journal={Solar Energy},
    volume={178},
    pages={37--47},
    year={2019},
    publisher={Elsevier}
}
@article{ram2020performance,
    title={Performance enhancement of solar {P}{V} systems applying {P}\&{O} assisted Flower Pollination Algorithm ({F}{P}{A})},
    author={Ram, J Prasanth and Pillai, Dhanup S and Ghias, Amer MYM and Rajasekar, N},
    journal={Solar Energy},
    volume={199},
    pages={214--229},
    year={2020},
    publisher={Elsevier}
}
```

I want to highlight second reference in the reference list. Due to journal requirements, I dont want to change the color of references, rather I specifically want to highlight the complete  reference. How can I do that?

Comment: No, that uses biblatex, whereas I am using bibtex. Also, that particular link relates to sorting

Comment: I want  to use something which performs same function as \hl{} for a particular reference which is written via bibtex

Comment: No please, this link does not give the solution to that. It just says to change the color of reference to any other color

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'll first describe which commands have to be added to the preamble (two variants, w/wo natbib), and then how to use them.

**If you or the document class (like elsarticle) loads `natbib`,** add the following lines to the preamble.

```
\newcommand\highlightReference[1]{%
  \expandafter\newcommand\csname highlightReference-#1\endcsname{}%
}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xapptocmd\@lbibitem{\hlbibitem{#2}}{}{}
\makeatother
\def\hlbibitem#1 #2\par{%
  \expandafter\ifx\csname highlightReference-#1\endcsname\relax
    #2\par
  \else
    \highlight{#2}\par
  \fi
}
```

**Otherwise, with the native bibliography handling of LaTeX,**
add the following lines to the preamble:

```
\newcommand\highlightReference[1]{%
  \expandafter\newcommand\csname highlightReference-#1\endcsname{}%
}
\let\oldbibitem\bibitem
\def\bibitem#1 #2\par{%
  \expandafter\ifx\csname highlightReference-#1\endcsname\relax
    \oldbibitem{#1}#2\par
  \else
    \oldbibitem{#1}\highlight{#2}\par
  \fi
}
```

**Then define the command** `\highlight{...}` the way you want to have your references highlighted. To underline them, use

```
\usepackage{soul}
\newcommand\highlight[1]{\ul{#}}
```

If you want to highlight by a yellow background, use

```
\usepackage{color,soul}
\newcommand\highlight[1]{\hl{#1}}
```

If you want to highlight by typesetting the words in red, use

```
\usepackage{color}
\newcommand\highlight[1]{\textcolor{red}{#1}}
```

The last solution is the most stable one, since the `soul` package may get into troubles if the highlighted text contains certain commands (error 'reconstruction failed').

**Finally, indicate which bib entries should be highlighted** by adding commands `\highlightReference{KEY}` for every reference, with `KEY` being the label you also use in the `\cite` command.

---

**Example: document class `article`, bibliography style `IEEEtran`, yellow background**

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\highlightReference[1]{%
  \expandafter\newcommand\csname highlightReference-#1\endcsname{}%
}
\let\oldbibitem\bibitem
\def\bibitem#1 #2\par{%
  \expandafter\ifx\csname highlightReference-#1\endcsname\relax
    \oldbibitem{#1}#2\par
  \else
    \oldbibitem{#1}\highlight{#2}\par
  \fi
}
\usepackage{color,soul}
\newcommand\highlight[1]{\hl{#1}}
\begin{document}

This is the file \cite{kang2020energy,pilakkat2019improved,ram2020performance}

\highlightReference{pilakkat2019improved}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{abc}  

\end{document}
```

---

**Example: document class `elsarticle` with option `authoryear`, bibliography style `abbrvnat`, underlined**

[image]

```
\documentclass[authoryear]{elsarticle}
\newcommand\highlightReference[1]{%
  \expandafter\newcommand\csname highlightReference-#1\endcsname{}%
}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xapptocmd\@lbibitem{\hlbibitem{#2}}{}{}
\makeatother
\def\hlbibitem#1 #2\par{%
  \expandafter\ifx\csname highlightReference-#1\endcsname\relax
    #2\par
  \else
    \highlight{#2}\par
  \fi
}
\usepackage{soul}
\newcommand\highlight[1]{\ul{#1}}
\begin{document}

This is the file \cite{kang2020energy,pilakkat2019improved,ram2020performance}

\highlightReference{pilakkat2019improved}
\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}
\bibliography{abc}  

\end{document}
```

---

**Example: document class `article` with package `natbib` and option `authoryear`, bibliography style `plainnat`, red text**

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}
\newcommand\highlightReference[1]{%
  \expandafter\newcommand\csname highlightReference-#1\endcsname{}%
}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xapptocmd\@lbibitem{\hlbibitem{#2}}{}{}
\makeatother
\def\hlbibitem#1 #2\par{%
  \expandafter\ifx\csname highlightReference-#1\endcsname\relax
    #2\par
  \else
    \highlight{#2}\par
  \fi
}
\usepackage{color}
\newcommand\highlight[1]{\textcolor{red}{#1}}
\begin{document}

This is the file \cite{kang2020energy,pilakkat2019improved,ram2020performance}

\highlightReference{pilakkat2019improved}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{abc}  

\end{document}
```

Comment: I dont want to underline, I want to highlight during revision of paper

Comment: @ShJ Well, then replace `\ul` by whatever you want to do to the reference ...

Comment: @ShJ I have modified the code to make the highlighting explicit, with examples showing underlining as well as coloring the background in yellow.

Comment: Due to soul package reconstruction failed error, I have to use \newcommand\highlight[1]{\hl{\mbox{#1}}}, but, when I use this, the whole highlighted reference spreads across a single column, whereas all other references are in two columns type format. Can you please tell What can be done for this

Comment: @ShJ If you put something into an `\mbox` command, it will not break across lines, so it is not a surprise that such lines will stick out to the other column (and beyond). I'm afraid there is no general solution, as long as you want to use background coloring. I have added a third option to my answer, coloring the text in red. This should work more reliably than the `soul` package. Otherwise, if you absolutely need background coloring and the `soul` package, you have to find out which command in your bibliography leads to the failed reconstruction, and try to do without it.

Comment: @gernot, strangely this does not seem to work under elsarticle, that's a shame becuase it's a very good idea. Any way to overcome this issue? thanks

Comment: Hey, is there a way this works with multiple cite entries? I have to highlight all newly added references in an article. This solution only highlights one of them

Comment: @Raphael What exactly do you mean? Something like `\highlightReference{A}\highlightReference{B}\highlightReference{C}` should work, if you want to highlight the references with the keys `A`, `B` and `C`.

Comment: @gernot Never mind, I had a space just before the citekey `\highlighReference{ C}`. I assumed the command would strip any whitespace. After removing that it works prefectly!

Comment: @umby Sorry, I missed your comment. Probably too late for you: I've added a solution for documents using `natbib`, like `elsarticle`.

Comment: @gernot still usefull, many thanks!